# Remove decimal and comma and digits from price in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make sure that any of these combinations - Will always display the rounded digit with no decimals or no commas. Example

```
1,200.00 should output = 1200
12.33 should output = 12
123.34 should output = 123
1,434 should output = 1434
165,33 should output = 165
250.00 should output = 250
259,00 should output = 259
```

I have tried:

```
var currency = "$1,100.00";
var number = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```

And my latest:

```
var priceTotal = parseFloat(price.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, ''));
```

But this does not work well with comma. It must always be display without comma, dot or the last digits.

Comment: you need an integer or a string is fine?

Comment: I think it should be integer as later on I am going to write conditional classes to see if the value is greater than or less than 399

Comment: checkout the updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use `/[^0-9\.]/g` regex to replace **comma**, use `indexOf` for find the **position of comma** AND use `parseInt` to make that string into **integer**.

Please follow the below example::

```
var a = '1,200.00';
var b = '12.33';
var c = '123.34';
var d = '1,434';
var e = '165,33';
var f = '250.00';
var g = '259,00';
$(document).ready(function () {
    parseNumberCustom(a);
    parseNumberCustom(b);
    parseNumberCustom(c);
    parseNumberCustom(d);
    parseNumberCustom(e);
    parseNumberCustom(f);
    parseNumberCustom(g);
});
function parseNumberCustom(number_string) {
    var new_number = parseInt(number_string.indexOf(',') >= 3 ? number_string.split(',')[0] : number_string.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
    console.log('Before==>' + number_string + ', After==>' + new_number);
}
```

Comment: what will be output 25900. It's coming in my end

Comment: 259 should be the output.

Comment: why this you want, can you please tell. for "1,200.00' you want 1200 AND for "259,00.00" you want 259

Comment: That is what I need

Comment: Or if 2400,98 then what will be the output

Comment: 2400 should be the output

Comment: 2400 or 2401? You said you want it rounded.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid please follow my recent updated answer

Comment: This needs a return statement to return the new number.
return new_number;

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


   

$("#Convert").click(function(){


 var currency1 = $("#mode").val()

if (currency1.indexOf(",") >= 0 && currency1.indexOf(".") >= 0) 
{
var intvalue =(parseInt(currency1.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')));
alert(intvalue)
}
if (currency1.indexOf(".") >= 0 && currency1.indexOf(",") < 0)
{
var intvalue = Math.floor( currency1 );
alert(intvalue)
}
if (currency1.indexOf(",") >= 0 && currency1.indexOf(".") < 0) 
{
var streetaddress= currency1.substr(0, currency1.indexOf(',')); 
alert(streetaddress)

}
})  

});

</script>
<body>

<div class="table-responsive container">
Enter Value:
<input type=Text id="mode" text="Switch Mode" class="Form-control" value="" >
<input type=Button id="Convert" text="Switch Mode" class="btn btn-primary" value="Convert" >


  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) method to round a number or use `Math.floor` method in case you need the lower value.

```
var number = Math.round( 
   currency
     // convert the comma seperated decimal part to dot seperated
     .replace(/\D(\d{2})$/, '.$1') 
     // replace all non-digit dot characters
     .replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '')
);
```

```js
['1,200.00', '12,33', '123.34', '1,434', '$1,100.16'].forEach(function(currency) {
  var number = Math.round(currency.replace(/\D(\d{2})$/, '.$1').replace(/[^\d.]+/g, ""));
  console.log(currency + ' => ' + number)
})
```

**FYI :** There is no need to escape `.` within the character class.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid : what is the expected output?

Comment: `259,00` should be `259` there should never be trailing decimal digits or dots or commas as my question states

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid : how can we understand which is a thousand separator or a decimal part ???

Comment: Can you check my jsFiddle with your code. Not working: https://jsfiddle.net/n21hr57s/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137429/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-theblackbenzkid).

Answer (score 1):

try to use parseInt method

```js
    var a = '1,200.00';
    var b = '12.33';
    var c = '123.34';
    var d = '1,434';
    var e = '165,33';
    var f = '250.00';
    var g = '259,00';
    console.log(parseInt(a.replace(/\,(\d\d)$/, ".$1").replace(',','')));
    console.log(parseInt(b.replace(/\,(\d\d)$/, ".$1").replace(',','')));
    console.log(parseInt(c.replace(/\,(\d\d)$/, ".$1").replace(',','')));
    console.log(parseInt(d.replace(/\,(\d\d)$/, ".$1").replace(',','')));
    console.log(parseInt(e.replace(/\,(\d\d)$/, ".$1").replace(',','')));
    console.log(parseInt(f.replace(/\,(\d\d)$/, ".$1").replace(',','')));
    console.log(parseInt(g.replace(/\,(\d\d)$/, ".$1").replace(',','')));
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity - this was a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the input always has two decimals (when there there's any) this should work:

```
function toNumber(string) {
    string = string.replace(/[^\d\,\.]/g, '');
    let commaNotation = /^\d+(\.\d{3})?\,\d{2}$/.test(string);
    let result = commaNotation ?
        Math.round(parseFloat(string.replace(/[^\d\,]/g, '').replace(/,/, '.'))) :
        Math.round(parseFloat(string.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '')));
    return result;
};
```

You can opt to use **`Math.floor()`** instead of **`Math.round()`** if you don't want to round up when >= 0.50.